# Iterating through entire Pandas Dataframe using column and row as arguments

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have this empty pandas dataframe and a function value(x,y) which takes in 2 arguments, the row number and the column number of the point in the pandas dataframe. I was wondering if there is a simpler way to iterate through the entire empty dataframe using these arguments, using df.apply perhaps.

I know it is possible to go through each individual column and run df.apply on the separate columns, but is it possible to do it without running any loops or what so ever.

Essentially, I am looking for something like this which I can run on the entire dataframe

```
df_copy.apply(lambda x: myfunction(x.value, x.column))
```

However, x.column does not exist, so it there is another way to do it or am I doing something wrong

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Please review [ask], as well as create a [mcve]

Comment: @user3483203 does that provide a bit more clarification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `name` and `index` attributes of a series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(1, index = np.arange(10,51,10), columns = np.arange(5))
```

Show input dataframe

```
    0  1  2  3  4
10  1  1  1  1  1
20  1  1  1  1  1
30  1  1  1  1  1
40  1  1  1  1  1
50  1  1  1  1  1
```

Let's define custom fuction and use rows as columns to do a calcuation.

```
def f(x):
    #add row values to column values
    return x.name + x.index

df.apply(f)
```

Output:

```
     0   1   2   3   4
10  10  11  12  13  14
20  20  21  22  23  24
30  30  31  32  33  34
40  40  41  42  43  44
50  50  51  52  53  54
```

Note:  `apply` is passing each column of the dataframe(which is a pd.Series) into the function f.   Each series has an attribute `name` which is the column heading, and `index`, which is dataframe row index.  So, function, f returns a calculated pd.Series for each column of the dataframe and is put back together as a dataframe.

Answering question in comments, let's use strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(1, index=['Ted','Bill','Ralph','John','Tim'], columns=['A','B','C','D','E'])

def f(x):
    #Concatenate row values with column values
    return x.index + '_' + x.name

df.apply(f)
```

OR use lambda function

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.index + '_' + x.name)
```

Output:

```
             A        B        C        D        E
Ted      Ted_A    Ted_B    Ted_C    Ted_D    Ted_E
Bill    Bill_A   Bill_B   Bill_C   Bill_D   Bill_E
Ralph  Ralph_A  Ralph_B  Ralph_C  Ralph_D  Ralph_E
John    John_A   John_B   John_C   John_D   John_E
Tim      Tim_A    Tim_B    Tim_C    Tim_D    Tim_E
```

Comment: So this works, however, x.name and x.index are RangeIndex Objects - is there anyway to convert these values to integers

Comment: Yes, I have attached an example in the soluton.